# iOS speed tracker app

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

We all know running tracker apps, such as Nike Running, RunKeeper, Runtastic etc. But i need app with a bit difference in functionality.

My ideal running application should track and report it to me (by voice) my speed every 30 seconds or 100 meter. (May be i can change this factor in settings).

Do you know some apps with such feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://abvio.com/runmeter/ will speak your stats:

- Hear stats automatically at time or distance intervals, or on-demand with your earphone remote.

I've reported several bugs and enhancements to the developer and they have many features baked into the app and tuning of parameters if needed. I would buy their app on the assumption it can cycle that fast and contact the developer if you need a setting to get the level of detail you need. The engineering behind their use of GPS is excellent. You'll need their assistance in tuning the filtering to avoid false alerts when noise places you more than 100m from the last fix in a shorter period of time than you can cover on foot.